# IBM Rhapsody accessor generation using references

Tags: c++, rhapsody

I have created a C++ project in IBM Rhapsody 8.1.5 and generate code using the in-built auto-coder feature.

I have used composition associations to create instances of classes throughout the model and would like to use the GetGenerate feature to automatically generate accessors for these in the form of References.

To achieve this I have globally selected CG::Relation::GetGenerate and set CPP_CG::Relation::ScalarContainment to Reference.

This results in code like the following...

```
MyClass1 itsMyClass1;

MyClass1& MyClass2::getItsMyClass1() const {
    return (MyClass1&) &itsMyClass1;
}
```

At compile time this produces the following error: invalid cast of an rvalue expression of type 'const MyClass1*' to type 'MyClass1&'

This generated accessor function should be without the extra '&' like this:

```
MyClass1& MyClass2::getItsMyClass1() const {
    return (MyClass1&) itsMyClass1;
}
```

I can't find any settings to affect this in the Rhapsody properties, does anyone know if there is a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a property which suites the need:

look for **OMContainers::EmbeddedScalar::Get** and remove the leading **&** there